# Нужно сделать анимацию header на 320px и 992px через js, но код работает только на одном из поинтов

Tags: javascript

Есть два файла header-320px.js и header-992px.js. Анимация присутствует только на 992px

```js
// код с файла header-320px.js

const header320px = document.querySelector('#header-s');

document.onscroll = function(){
    const scroll320px = window.scrollY;
   
    if(scroll320px > 85){
      header320px.classList.add('active320px');
    } else {
      header320px.classList.remove('active320px');
}

// код с файла header-992px.js

const header = document.querySelector('#header-scroll');
const headerH = document.querySelector('#header-scroll').clientHeight;

document.onscroll = function(){
  const scroll = window.scrollY;

  if(scroll > headerH){
    header.classList.add('activeh');
  } else {
    header.classList.remove('activeh');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы присвоите условной переменной `a` значение `10`, а потом значение `20`, будет ли она иметь одновременно два значения? Здесь принцип тот же: вы сначала записываете в `onscroll` одну функцию, а потом другую. Соответственно будет работать только последняя.

Используйте для этих целей `addEventListener`([документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)):

```js
// код с файла header-320px.js

const header320px = document.querySelector('#header-s');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    const scroll320px = window.scrollY;
   
    if(scroll320px > 85){
      header320px.classList.add('active320px');
    } else {
      header320px.classList.remove('active320px');
})

// код с файла header-992px.js

const header = document.querySelector('#header-scroll');
const headerH = document.querySelector('#header-scroll').clientHeight;

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  const scroll = window.scrollY;

  if(scroll > headerH){
    header.classList.add('activeh');
  } else {
    header.classList.remove('activeh');
  }
})
```